# Intermittent access to Azure Fileshares?

Tags: java, c#, c++, azure

We have a number of applications that are running in a VM in Azure, using Azure Fileshares for disk.

We're getting reports from ops that they're seeing intermittent issues with our apps not being able to access disk. That for sixty or seconds or so, any attempt to access disk will simply fail.

So we've been tasked with adding a sort of retry mechanism to the file access in our applications.

Just to make it interesting, some of these are written in C#, some in C++, and some in Java.

The task on failure is to wait a bit, and retry, and then if we don't succeed in a set amount of time to abort the application and quit.

The start is to create a static class containing methods that wrap the low-level filesystem functions. Replace all calls to ::fopen(), for example, with calls to FileWrapper::fopen().

And then to add the retry logic in FileWrapper::fopen().

The problem I'm having is I have no idea how to determine what is a failure.

Suppose, for example, I'm doing an fopen() on a file. The file may or may not exist. Sometimes I don't expect it to exist, sometimes I do. That fopen() failed may mean that the Azure filesystem is unavailable, it may simply mean that there is no such file.

And if we treat every failure as a system failure, and shut down, as we've been asked to do, we'll be shutting down our apps immediately on start.

The whole approach simply seems wrong to me.

And we have no info about what is actually happening when these incidents occur because, oddly enough, nothing is being written to the log files.

Has anyone run into issues with Azure Filesystems being intermittently unavailable?

Have ideas on how to detect that this has happened, in C#, C++, and Java?

Comment: BTW, once a language is compiled into an executable, the language that the executable was written in doesn't matter anymore.  The OS sees an executable file (regardless of how it was created) and processes it.  Scripts and Java are usually different because they are interpreted at execution.

Comment: The way a language interacts with the OS can be different. The low-level file access functions in C# don't report errors in the same way that the C/C++ functions do.